# How to change properties of imported SVG by id in react?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, svg

I want to change the properties of imported SVGs by addressing the ids inside the SVG.

The SVG is created in Inkscape. There I define the ids, too. My intention is to make more complex SVGs and change the colors inside the SVG depending on the app status. So, I have to use the unique ids as a reference I can easily define in a tool like Inkscape.

After that I convert the SVG to JSX with this tool: [svg2jsx.com/](https://svg2jsx.com/). After all the SVG is imported as an ReactComponent.

The SVG for testing purposes (testCircle.svg):

```
<svg
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  id="svg1913"
  width="250px"
  height="250px"
  version="1.1"
  viewBox="0 0 50 50"
>
  <g id="topLayer" transform="translate(-82.487 -82.487)">
    <circle
      id="testCircle"
      cx="107.487"
      cy="107.487"
      r="15.524"
      fill="#77f"
      strokeWidth="0.6"
    ></circle>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Here the code snippet to show the SVG. I want to change the properties of the SVG from this file by addressing `id="testCircle"`.

```
import {ReactComponent as TestImg} from './testCircle.svg';

export default function TestImageCircle() {
    return(
        <div>
            <TestImg />
        </div>
    );
}
```

Thanks!